# arduino uno IR receiver motor control

Tags: c, arduino-uno

Hi I'm new and have had a bit of a search for a solution to this problem, but is appears to be unique.

I have an arduino uno and I want to control multiple dc motors speeds and directions with it wirelessly with an IR remote. I have managed to attach a motor and get the arduino to turn it on by pressing a button on the remote control, however I cannot get it to turn off by pressing another button. What happens is when I open the serial monitor for the arduino, it recognises the first IR signal and turns the motor on. However when the motor is spinning (and only when the motor is spinning) the arduino detects an endless stream of IR signals which stop the arduino from receiving any real ones. This occurs even when the IR receiver is pulled out of the circuit. I am using the analogWrite() function to turn the motor on and if I lower the pulse enough that the motor doesn't turn (but makes a noise) it can be started and stopped with the remote because it doesn't turn and therefore doesn't make the arduino receive IR signals. If I make the pulse low enough that I can forcibly stop the motor, the IR signals stop.

I have no idea what is happening and have tried altering my code and the circuits.

Here is the code I am using - I copied and modified one from adafruit which reads IR commands.

```
/* Raw IR commander

This sketch/program uses the Arduno and a PNA4602 to 
decode IR received.  It then attempts to match it to a previously
recorded IR signal

Code is public domain, check out www.ladyada.net and adafruit.com
for more tutorials! 
*/

// We need to use the 'raw' pin reading methods
// because timing is very important here and the digitalRead()
// procedure is slower!
//uint8_t IRpin = 2;
// Digital pin #2 is the same as Pin D2 see
// http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168 for the 'raw' pin mapping
#define IRpin_PIN      PIND
#define IRpin          2

// the maximum pulse we'll listen for - 65 milliseconds is a long time
#define MAXPULSE 65000
#define NUMPULSES 50

// what our timing resolution should be, larger is better
// as its more 'precise' - but too large and you wont get
// accurate timing
#define RESOLUTION 20 

// What percent we will allow in variation to match the same code
#define FUZZINESS 20

// we will store up to 100 pulse pairs (this is -a lot-)
uint16_t pulses[NUMPULSES][2];  // pair is high and low pulse 
uint8_t currentpulse = 0; // index for pulses we're storing

#include "own_codes.h"
int numberpulses = 0;
int a;

void setup(void) {
Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Ready to decode IR!");
}

void loop(void) {

  numberpulses = listenForIR();

  Serial.print("Heard ");
  Serial.print(numberpulses);
  Serial.println("-pulse long IR signal");

  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Zero,sizeof(Zero)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Zero");
  analogWrite(3, 100);
}
  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Eight,sizeof(Eight)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Eight");
  analogWrite(3,39);
}
  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Nine,sizeof(Nine)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Nine");
  analogWrite(3,0);
}
  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Minus,sizeof(Minus)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Minus");
  analogWrite(3, 31);
  delay(5000);
  analogWrite(3, 0);
}
  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Return,sizeof(Return)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Return");
  analogWrite(3, 0);
}
  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Red,sizeof(Red)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Red");
  analogWrite(3, 100);
  delay(2000);
  analogWrite(3, 0);
}
  if (IRcompare(numberpulses, Green,sizeof(Green)/4)) {
  Serial.println("Green");
  analogWrite(3, 255);
  delay(1500);
  analogWrite(3, 200);
  delay(1500);
  analogWrite(3, 150);
  delay(1500);
  analogWrite(3, 100);
  delay(1500);
  analogWrite(3, 50);
  delay(3000);
  analogWrite(3, 0);
}

}

//KGO: added size of compare sample. Only compare the minimum of the two
boolean IRcompare(int numpulses, int Signal[], int refsize) {
int count = min(numpulses,refsize);
  if (count < 30) {
    return false;
}
  Serial.print("count set to: ");
  Serial.println(count);
  for (int i=0; i< count-1; i++) {
    int oncode = pulses[i][1] * RESOLUTION / 10;
    int offcode = pulses[i+1][0] * RESOLUTION / 10;

#ifdef DEBUG    
    Serial.print(oncode); // the ON signal we heard
    Serial.print(" - ");
    Serial.print(Signal[i*2 + 0]); // the ON signal we want 
#endif   

    // check to make sure the error is less than FUZZINESS percent
    if ( abs(oncode - Signal[i*2 + 0]) <= (Signal[i*2 + 0] * FUZZINESS /      100)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print(" (ok)");
#endif
    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print(" (x)");
#endif
      // we didn't match perfectly, return a false match
      return false;
    }


#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print("  \t"); // tab
    Serial.print(offcode); // the OFF signal we heard
    Serial.print(" - ");
    Serial.print(Signal[i*2 + 1]); // the OFF signal we want 
#endif    

    if ( abs(offcode - Signal[i*2 + 1]) <= (Signal[i*2 + 1] * FUZZINESS / 100)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print(" (ok)");
#endif
    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print(" (x)");
#endif
      // we didn't match perfectly, return a false match
      return false;
    }

#ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println();
#endif
  }
  // Everything matched!
  return true;
}

int listenForIR(void) {
  currentpulse = 0;

  while (1) {
    uint16_t highpulse, lowpulse;  // temporary storage timing
    highpulse = lowpulse = 0; // start out with no pulse length

//  while (digitalRead(IRpin)) { // this is too slow!
    while (IRpin_PIN & (1 << IRpin)) {
       // pin is still HIGH

       // count off another few microseconds
       highpulse++;
       delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);

       // If the pulse is too long, we 'timed out' - either nothing
       // was received or the code is finished, so print what
       // we've grabbed so far, and then reset

       // KGO: Added check for end of receive buffer
       if (((highpulse >= MAXPULSE) && (currentpulse != 0))|| currentpulse == NUMPULSES) {
         return currentpulse;
       }
    }
    // we didn't time out so lets stash the reading
    pulses[currentpulse][0] = highpulse;

    // same as above
    while (! (IRpin_PIN & _BV(IRpin))) {
       // pin is still LOW
       lowpulse++;
       delayMicroseconds(RESOLUTION);
        // KGO: Added check for end of receive buffer
        if (((lowpulse >= MAXPULSE)  && (currentpulse != 0))|| currentpulse == NUMPULSES) {
         return currentpulse;
       }
    }
    pulses[currentpulse][2] = lowpulse;

    // we read one high-low pulse successfully, continue!
    currentpulse++;
  }
}
void printpulses(void) {
  Serial.println("\n\r\n\rReceived: \n\rOFF \tON");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < currentpulse; i++) {
    Serial.print(pulses[i][0] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
    Serial.print(" usec, ");
    Serial.print(pulses[i][3] * RESOLUTION, DEC);
    Serial.println(" usec");
  }

  // print it in a 'array' format
  Serial.println("int IRsignal[] = {");
  Serial.println("// ON, OFF (in 10's of microseconds)");
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < currentpulse-1; i++) {
    Serial.print("\t"); // tab
    Serial.print(pulses[i][4] * RESOLUTION / 10, DEC);
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(pulses[i+1][0] * RESOLUTION / 10, DEC);
    Serial.println(",");
  }
   Serial.print("\t"); // tab
   Serial.print(pulses[currentpulse-1][5] * RESOLUTION / 10, DEC);
   Serial.print(", 0};");
 }
```

Here are links the pictures of the circuit, I have combined the IR receiver circuit with the motor circuit. (I'm not allowed to post images directly)

IR receiver: https://learn.adafruit.com/system/assets/assets/000/000/555/medium800/light_arduinopna4602.gif?1396763990

Motor circuit:
http://cdn.instructables.com/F9L/KDFG/GU7FXUMH/F9LKDFGGU7FXUMH.MEDIUM.jpg

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some information about motor interference:

http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/stop-noise-from-motor-to-arduino-mcu.90733/

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=60247.0